# Datagrams in java

Tags: java, networking, datagram

Is possibility in java without using native functions to send datagrams ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure - here's an [example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html).

And here's the Javadoc for [DatagramPacket](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See the [DatagramPacket](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html) class and [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html) for more details. Datagrams are supported in standard Java J2SE.